# How do I group together and return multiple values associated with the same date?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So basically as an example, here's a table of foods and the date they were consumed on by different people

consumption

| user_id | food | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 12-DEC-09 |
| 1 | banana | 12-DEC-09 |
| 1 | strawberry | 13-DEC-09 |
| 2 | apple | 14-DEC-09 |
| 2 | apple | 15-DEC-09 |
| 2 | orange | 15-DEC-09 |

I want to select all foods that each user_id ate on each unique date, so the output looks something like:

| user_id | food | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple, banana | 12-DEC-09 |
| 1 | strawberry | 13-DEC-09 |
| 2 | apple | 14-DEC-09 |
| 2 | apple, orange | 15-DEC-09 |

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT food
FROM consumption
WHERE food IN (
    SELECT food
    FROM consumption
    GROUP BY food, `date`
)
GROUP BY user_id;
```

But I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The group in your case is rows group where both user_id and date is the same. Hence you must group by these two columns.

You need all food names concatenated into single value within a group. Hence you must use according aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(food) food_list, `date`
FROM consumption
GROUP BY user_id, `date`;
```

Comment: Note: `date` is not a _reserved_ keyword in MySQL, though nothing wrong with escaping in backticks as on some other databases not doing so might cause problems +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `DATE` is a keyword. I always quote such object names, even when there is no ambiguity and it can be correctly distinguished as object name. It's a habit.